# Sonos devices return the same information with 3 seperate UUID's over SSDP

Tags: sonos, ssdp

While trying to write an SSDP implementation I noticed that I get 6 Sonos speakers where I only have 2. Further research leads to the discovery that I get 3 separate responses per speaker. Those being: BASE, BASE_MR, BASE_MS

The rest of the responses are the exact same for every BASE UUID. Can somebody tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I have determined that BASE is the root device and _MR and _MS are subdevices